# iPad 2 Wifi + 3G With iOS 4.3.3 has no multitasking gestures?

Tags: ipad, multitasking, ios

I recently bought an iPad 2 Wifi + 3G. It is not Jail broken and it is completely genuine. It has iOS 4.3.3 pre-installed. I have not updated my iOS yet as I have just bought it today.

I didn't find any option like "Enable Multitasking Gestures" under the General tab of Settings.

Has Apple disabled it in iOS 4.3 now? Or is something wrong with my iPad?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely you used that iPad for development, when you connect it to XCode, and set it "Use for development" the Enable gestures switch will appear.

Comment: ok thanks I will try out that soon and get back to you :)

Answer (score 2):

## iOS 5 Feature

I think your thinking of the neat three-finger swipe that can be used to switch between apps on the iPad?  This is actually a demoed feature of iOS 5, which has not yet been released to the general public.  Check for the software update in September when iOS 5 is released. :)

You can learn more about the features of iOS 5 of Apple's features page. http://www.apple.com/ios/ios5/features.html

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actually I had it working in my other iPad 2 which had the same iOS version 4.3.3 but it was around 2 months back and in that iPad 2, it still works but not in the newly bought one.

Answer (score 1):

They did disable this feature in 4.3.3 but it worked on 4.3 I think. It will come back again in iOS 5.

Comment: Yeah must be. But it is quite weird that they put this feature in iOS 4.3 and pulled it back in iOS 4.3.3 and then again launching it in iOS 5.